# Breaking up an SQL query into PHP variables

Tags: php, html, mysql, arrays

I've started working with PHP the last couple of weeks and I'm currently building a website that searches tables for alcoholic products in different stores.

Is there a way to divide up a result into individual variables in PHP? Such as if I ask for all the details of a store in a single query could I then divide that result into $storename, $storelocation etc?

Comment: What is the reason for needing them as those variable names? When you get the result from the database, you can just reference them, for example `print $result[0]['fieldName'];` ... Or in a loop, `foreach($result as $row) { print $row['fieldName']; }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can do it:-

1. define variables outside the loop that you want to use as an array variable
2. use them in assigning values in loop.

Check below:-

```
$name_of_store = Array();
$location_of_store = Array();
 while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $name_of_store[] = $row['name_of_store']; // suppose your column name is name_of_store        
        $location_of_store[] = $row['location_of_store'];// suppose your column name is location_of_store        
    }
```

Now you can use both variables any were you want.thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do this would be something like this:

Firstly connect your database and make the query:-

```
$db = mysqli($host, $user, $password, $database);

$query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM `alcohol_products` WHERE `product_name` = '".$query_string."'");
```

Then check the amount of rows returned and loop the results into an array as follows:-

```
if ($query->num_rows = 0) {
    echo 'Sorry, no results where found.';
} else {
    while ($row = $query->fetch_assoc()) {
        $storename[] = $row['storename'];
        $storelocation[] = $row['storelocation'];
    }

    for ($i = 0; $ < count($storename); $i++) {
        echo $storename.' - '.$storelocation.' <br />';
    }
}
```

Our database would return results and list them in this format:

Walmart - Chicago 
Walmart - New York

Like that...

Though, because you're showing all the stores with that product. You may want to go down the route of storing arrays in the 'storename' and 'storelocation' as the least complicated way of storing their data.